# Second Line in an Apache-POI chart with seperate axis

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi

Hi this code taken from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192804/how-do-i-add-a-second-line-with-a-second-axis-to-an-xddfchart-in-poi-4-0-1) is working as expected, but I want exactly the same Chart but in an Excel-Sheet

```
package eu.flexsolution.task.excel;

import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;

public class TEst {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument()) {

        // create the data
        String[] categories = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
        Double[] values1 = new Double[] { 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d, 6d, 7d, 8d, 9d };
        Double[] values2 = new Double[] { 200d, 300d, 400d, 500d, 600d, 700d, 800d, 900d, 1000d };

        // create the chart
        XWPFChart chart = document.createChart(15 * Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER, 10 * Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER);

        // create data sources
        int numOfPoints = categories.length;
        String categoryDataRange = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 0, 0));
        String valuesDataRange1 = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 1, 1));
        String valuesDataRange2 = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 2, 2));
        XDDFDataSource<String> categoriesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories, categoryDataRange, 0);
        XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values1, valuesDataRange1,
                1);
        XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values2, valuesDataRange2,
                2);

        // first line chart
        XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
        leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
        XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
        XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData1);
        chart.plot(data);

        solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.BLUE);

        // second line chart
        // bottom axis must be there but must not be visible
        bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        bottomAxis.setVisible(false);

        XDDFValueAxis rightAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
        rightAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX);

        // set correct cross axis
        bottomAxis.crossAxis(rightAxis);
        rightAxis.crossAxis(bottomAxis);

        data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, rightAxis);
        series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData2);
        chart.plot(data);

        // correct the id and order, must not be 0 again because there is one line
        // series already
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(1).getSerArray(0).getIdx().setVal(1);
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(1).getSerArray(0).getOrder().setVal(1);

        solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.RED);

        // Write the output to a file
        try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordXDDFChart.docx")) {
            document.write(fileOut);
        }
    }
}

private static void solidLineSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
    XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
    XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
    line.setFillProperties(fill);
    XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
    XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
    if (properties == null) {
        properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
    }
    properties.setLineProperties(line);
    series.setShapeProperties(properties);
}
}
```

So I modified the code like this to get an XLSX document, but the Chart isn't the same
[image: chart in excel]

```
package eu.flexsolution.task.excel;


import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class TEst {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (XSSFWorkbook document = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
        XSSFSheet chartSheet = document.createSheet("chart");
        
        // create the data
        String[] categories = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
        Double[] values1 = new Double[] { 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d, 6d, 7d, 8d, 9d };
        Double[] values2 = new Double[] { 200d, 300d, 400d, 500d, 600d, 700d, 800d, 900d, 1000d };

        // create the chart
        XSSFDrawing drawing = chartSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 40);
        XDDFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
        
        // create data sources
        int numOfPoints = categories.length;
        String categoryDataRange = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 0, 0));
        String valuesDataRange1 = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 1, 1));
        String valuesDataRange2 = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 2, 2));
        XDDFDataSource<String> categoriesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories, categoryDataRange, 0);
        XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values1, valuesDataRange1,
                1);
        XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values2, valuesDataRange2,
                2);

        // first line chart
        XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
        leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
        XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
        XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData1);
        chart.plot(data);

        solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.BLUE);

        // second line chart
        // bottom axis must be there but must not be visible
        bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        bottomAxis.setVisible(false);

        XDDFValueAxis rightAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
        rightAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX);

        // set correct cross axis
        bottomAxis.crossAxis(rightAxis);
        rightAxis.crossAxis(bottomAxis);

        data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, rightAxis);
        series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData2);
        chart.plot(data);

        // correct the id and order, must not be 0 again because there is one line
        // series already
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(1).getSerArray(0).getIdx().setVal(1);
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(1).getSerArray(0).getOrder().setVal(1);

        solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.RED);

        // Write the output to a file
        try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordXDDFChart.xlsx")) {
            document.write(fileOut);
        }
    }
}

private static void solidLineSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
    XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
    XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
    line.setFillProperties(fill);
    XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
    XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
    if (properties == null) {
        properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
    }
    properties.setLineProperties(line);
    series.setShapeProperties(properties);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that for a `Word` (`XWPF`) chart, the data are stored in a `Excel` workbook which is embedded in the `Word` file. There the data can be given as arrays and handled via `XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray`. This then fills the embedded `Excel` data sheet.

But for a `Excel`(`XSSF`) chart the data needs to be in a `Excel` data sheet. Of course `Excel` will not embedding a `Excel` sheet in it's files as it has worksheets already. So for `Excel` the data needs to be in a worksheet and needs to be handled via `XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange` or `XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange` then.

Complete example which creates the `Excel` `XSSFChart`:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CreateExcelXDDFChart {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (XSSFWorkbook document = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
   XSSFSheet chartSheet = document.createSheet("chart");
   XSSFSheet dataSheet = document.createSheet("data");
        
   // create the data
   String[] categories = new String[] { "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9" };
   Double[] values1 = new Double[] { 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d, 6d, 7d, 8d, 9d };
   Double[] values2 = new Double[] { 200d, 300d, 400d, 500d, 600d, 700d, 800d, 900d, 1000d };
   int r = 0;
   for (String cat : categories) {
    dataSheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue(cat);
    dataSheet.getRow(r).createCell(1).setCellValue(values1[r]);
    dataSheet.getRow(r).createCell(2).setCellValue(values2[r]);
    r++;
   }
        
   // create the chart
   XSSFDrawing drawing = chartSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
   XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 40);
   XDDFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
        
   // create data sources
   int numOfPoints = categories.length;
   XDDFDataSource<String> categoriesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, numOfPoints-1, 0, 0));
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, numOfPoints-1, 1, 1));
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, numOfPoints-1, 2, 2));

   // first line chart
   XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
   leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
   XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
   XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData1);
   chart.plot(data);

   solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.BLUE);

   // second line chart
   // bottom axis must be there but must not be visible
   bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   bottomAxis.setVisible(false);

   XDDFValueAxis rightAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
   rightAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX);

   // set correct cross axis
   bottomAxis.crossAxis(rightAxis);
   rightAxis.crossAxis(bottomAxis);

   data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, rightAxis);
   series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData2);
   chart.plot(data);

   // correct the id and order, must not be 0 again because there is one line
   // series already
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(1).getSerArray(0).getIdx().setVal(1);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(1).getSerArray(0).getOrder().setVal(1);

   solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.RED);

   // Write the output to a file
   try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelXDDFChart.xlsx")) {
    document.write(fileOut);
   }
  }
 }

 private static void solidLineSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
  XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
  XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
  line.setFillProperties(fill);
  //XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
  XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries(index);
  XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
  if (properties == null) {
   properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
  }
  properties.setLineProperties(line);
  series.setShapeProperties(properties);
 }
}
```

Works using current `apache poi 4.1.2`.